# How to rename the json key in cakephp?

Tags: arrays, json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a JSON object with the following content:

```
[{"price_id":1501822498,"name":"abc"},
{"price_id":1501825921,"name":"xyz"}]
```

I want to change the "price_id" key to "id" so it would become

```
[{"id":1501822498,"name":"abc"},
{"id":1501825921,"name":"xyz"}]
```

How would I do that in cakephp?

my cakephp json code is

```
$searchitem = $this->MbPriceList->find('all' , [
 'fields' => [ 
  'price_id',
            'name' => 't1.item_name'
        ], 
        'join' => [
            'table' => 'mb_item_list', 
            'alias' => 't1', 
            'type' => 'INNER', 
            'conditions' => [
            't1.item_code = MbPriceList.item_code'
            ]
        ]
    ]) ->toArray();
```

Comment: did you import js files of typehead?

Comment: yes already imported

Comment: That link is not working. its not importing

Comment: That all link are all in my local url. its working for me.

Comment: what is the version of bootstrap?

Comment: **bootstrap.min.js** version or **bootstrap-typeahead.js** version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158927/discussion-between-dinesh-and-ganesh).